# Service-Based Database SQL Select statement with date not working

Tags: c#, sql-server, database

In my code less then, between and equal to dates are not working.

In datebase DueDate field is selected as date type not datetime

```
sqlString = "Select [VehiNo], [DueDate], [Works] From [Daily] Where [DueDate] <= '" + today.ToShortDateString() + "' and [ServiceDate] Is NULL";
MessageBox.Show(sqlString);

using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlString, conn))
{
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    dtDue.Load(reader);
}
if (dtDue.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    dataListOverDue.DataSource = dtDue;
    dataListOverDue.Columns["VehiNo"].HeaderText = "Vehicle No";
}
```

[Database Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ElcXN.png)

[Data Loaded in WinForm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Fu4X.png)

I have 3 data grid view and 3 sql statment each for finding today's due, due between today and next 15 days and due already pass the date.

I tried many things but none is working i don't know why.
I already tried parameters like this.

```
string sqlString = "Select [VehiNo], [DueDate], [Works] From [Daily] Where [DueDate]='@today' and [ServiceDate] Is NULL";
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@today", today.ToString());

sqlString = string.Format("Select [VehiNo], [DueDate], [Works] From [Daily] Where [DueDate] Between '@today' And '@next'");
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@today", today.ToString());
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@next", next.ToString());
```

Select with = return nothing

Select with between gives conversion fail error

Select with <= return all the dates as i shown in image.

Comment: If column is of  datetime type then why not use parameterized query. Formatting datetime value won't be needed then.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya I already tried it please check my edits.

Comment: Go thru the solution I posted below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the way you are generating the query and adding parameter to it.

You don't need to wrap the query parameters inside single quotes. Also you don't need to convert parameter value ToString() if datatype of column and parameter are matching.

Go thru following solution.

```
string sqlString = "Select [VehiNo], [DueDate], [Works] From [Daily] Where [DueDate] = @today and [ServiceDate] Is NULL";

var sqlCommand = new SqlCommand();
sqlCommand.CommandText = sqlString;
sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@today", SqlDbType.DateTime);
sqlCommand.Parameters["@today"].Value = today;

var next = today.AddDays(20);
sqlString = string.Format("Select [VehiNo], [DueDate], [Works] From [Daily] Where [DueDate] Between @today And @next");
sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@today", SqlDbType.DateTime);
sqlCommand.Parameters["@today"].Value = today;
sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@next", SqlDbType.DateTime);
sqlCommand.Parameters["@next"].Value = next;
```

This should resolve your issue.

Comment: I came to same solution hour befor but thank you. Can you please help me in my other question? As this site is very difficult understand and site say don't say thanks. So here i send you my other question link. Even i don't know this method of asking you is right or not.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42587017/how-to-move-cursor-into-maskedtextbox-c-sharp-winforms

Answer (score 0):

try following

```
string sqlFormattedDate = today.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff");
```

or

```
DateTime myDateTime = DateTime.Now;
string sqlFormattedDate = myDateTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```

and use sqlFormattedDate

Don't use string concatenation, use a parameterised query. Pass in a parameter value of type DateTime. This avoids the formatting issue altogether, improves performance for subsequent queries, and gets around the inherent vulnerabilities (SQL injection) that you lay yourself open to when forming SQL in this way.

```
"where @dateTime <= DateTimeField"
```